# Sending List through DatagramSocket?

Tags: java, list, sockets, client

I have a spreadsheet application in Java, and one of the features it provides (which I developed) is sheet sharing. Basically, anyone can be a client or a server because the app has both server and client code. The user who is the server creates the share, specifies the IP, and then the share is created and active (best case scenario) with the server listening for clients on its IP and selected port.

For auto-discovery, I am using DatagramSockets via UDP broadcasts, while the 'real communication' is TCP-based (after the client is already connected). However, I'm trying to send a `List` through that UDP socket and I don't know how to do it. That `List` contains the active shares on the server that I need to send to the client so it knows what it can connect to.

It goes like this:

Client -> looks for active servers by sending a packet to the network -> server listens and sends a packet back. This packet should be the `List` (if it is possible to send it via these kind of sockets).

Can anyone shed some light on my question? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your List to a byte[] before sending, and convert it back to a List on the reciever using Java Serialization.

```
    // Sender
    List list = new ArrayList();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
    outputStream.writeObject(list);
    outputStream.close();

    byte[] listData = out.toByteArray();


    // Reciever
    ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(listData));
    list = inputStream.readObject();
```

Just make sure all the objects you put in your List implements Serializable.

Comment: Thank you. Just a question: all my List objects are `ServerInstance`, this is an inner class in my `ServerShareInstance` main class. Should I serialize just the former?

Comment: If it's an inner class, it needs to be declared Serializable as well. If it extends another class that is Serializable or implements an interface that extends Serializable, you don't need to declare the class Serializable. As long as all objects in your object graph can be instances of Serializable, you're good. You will recieve a NotSerializableException if you try to write such an object to the ObjectOutputStream. You should also include a serialVersionUID field in the classes, this has to be the same in each JVM that deserialize your objects, so you should set it to a spesific value.

Comment: Turns out I was Serializing `Socket` lists, and that's not allowed (doesn't implement the interface) so it always threw that exception. I turned to `InetSocketAddress` since I only really need that IP and port, and it works great now. Thanks!

Comment: Great. PS: You can add the <code>transient</code> modifier to fields that you don't want to include in your serialized objects :)